# Spark data frame execution

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to understand the spark dataframe execution. I have gone through the logs and explain plan, but I am not clear. My question is say I have the spark program and I have some series of data frames like below which does something

```
df1 = gets some data
df2 = gets some other data
df3 = df1.join(df2....)
df4= df3.join(some other data set)
df5 = df3.join(some other data set)
d6 = d4.join(some other data set)
d7 = d5.join(some other data set)
d6.write...()
d7.write...()
```

Lets say above are the series of dataframe. So my question is, when d6.write is issued, does df1,df2,df3,df4 gets executed and when d7.write is issued, does again df1,df2,df3,d5 gets executed ? Is it a good idea to persist d3 dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

> when d6.write is issued, does df1,df2,df3,df4 gets executed and when d7.write is issued, does again df1,df2,df3,d5 gets executed ?

Ans: Yes

> Is it a good idea to persist d3 dataframe ?

Ans: Yes